# Overriding wordpress !important while still able to use javascript to work with it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found similar questions but none seem to touch the specific use case I have.

I made a custom webpage to be used with my works WordPress site. WordPress wraps the custom code in a container div and has the following CSS:

```
max-width: 1200px!important
width: 1200px!important;
```

The problems are:

1. its set as important so in order to overide it with just css I would have to make mine also important AND more specific as I have gathered from other posts here.
2. I need to be able to use Javascript to change the width on the fly, there is an event that causes this to happen frequently.
3. The width of my div needs to be the default value, where it just grows with content.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class to override the first one (it cascades) and set the width to `initial`.

Run the following snippet and click the `div` to toggle the `baz` class to see that it overrides the `foo` class. `bar` class is ignored since it is overridden by the `!important` rule in `foo`.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("div");

el.addEventListener('click', () => el.classList.contains("baz") ? el.classList.remove("baz") : el.classList.add("baz"));
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
}

.bar {
  background-color: green;
}

.baz {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  width: initial !important;
  height: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar baz"></div>
```